# How do I move to the beginning of text in a line, not to the beginning of line?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I just switched from Windows and I'm giving Xcode a try. It's really nice, but I have an annoyance when coding - I want to be able to quickly move to the beginning of text in a line of text. However, CMD+left arrow go to the beginning of line, leaving me to manually press right arrow until I get to the first letter.

Can I do something to get a similar behaviour as in Windows?

Comment: did you find any answer or workaround to this? have you tried clicking Cmd-Left and then Alt-Right?

Answer (score 1):

From the online OS X: Keyboard shortcuts page @ http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343z:

Command+ ▶︎ Move the text insertion point to the end of the current line
Command+ ◀︎ Move the text insertion point to the beginning of the current line
Command+ ▼ Move the text insertion point to the end of the document
Command+ ▲  Move the text insertion point to the beginning of the document
Option+ ▶︎  Move the text insertion point to the end of the next word
Option+ ◀︎  Move the text insertion point to the beginning of the previous word

with the ◀︎ icons being the arrow keys on full sized keyboard. Happy typing.

Comment: Unfortunately, Command+left moves to the beginning of the line, not the beginning of text in a line.

Comment: Yes, this just restates the same knowledge the asker already knew without providing any help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest way to achieve this is to press Cmd-Left and then Alt-Right

Answer (score 0):

Hold <kbd>Cmd</kbd>, then press <kbd>→</kbd> followed by <kbd>←</kbd>.

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> gets you to the end of the line. Then <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> gets you to the start of the text in the line.

This is technically two shortcuts, but it can be done in three keystrokes really fast. This has worked for me in Xcode 12 and 13.